# How to return an option when reading a vector

Tags: scala

Reading from a vector, I want to return none when trying to read an index that is out of bounds and some otherwise. Is there a standard method for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `lift`:

```
val v = Vector(1, 2, 3)
v.lift(0)  //Some(1)
v.lift(5)  //None
```

note this works for any partial function.